# Blender Cycles Render vs baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-baking

I am working on a point and click game, I build my scenes in 3D in Blender Cycles and export them to Unity. I am working very
hard lately to get the graphics at the highest edge but I stumbled on some things that makes me doubt how to make what I really want to make. The game I make is in this moment made with camera mapping, I made a scene in 3D and then use a rendered image, uv map the objects with project from view and put the image(s) on the objects. So the scenes look already nice, but now I just have the thought to make the game into full 3D, meaning that all objects can be seen from all sides, so therefore I need to uv map all the objects again, which is no problem by any means. But I did a lot of baking test into cycles and the baking textures look very different from the full rendered image/rendered textures. I mean to say that the rendered image is far better quality than the baking quality as far as I can see. I already read a lot of threads about it, and that one can't use fresnel or specific shaders (like glass etc) for the baking. So my question is: Is there a way or a method that is user-friendly and that I could somehow use rendered textures instead of baking for the whole object/s? I already thought about making the objects split into two so I can put two rendered images, one for the front and one for the backside, but this seems a bit tedious, and is double as much work. Is there another or better method for this or did I miss something? I hope someone that understands my problem could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "So my question is: Is there a way or a method that is user-friendly and that I could somehow use rendered textures instead of baking for the whole object/s?" So, if I understand your question, well, no, I think. Cycles rendering is not available in game. Baking cycles into texture you can then UV map or something is the best trick you can get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Well, if you would have an addon that would make 6 pictures like a skybox from an object, render all sides on high quality and put them in one texture atlas it would be a full 3D rendered object. But no such thing exist as far as I know, which seems kind of strange..

Comment: So I basically want to camera map it from the rendered textures but without that kind of process because the difference is that if one creates their own scene (so not making something from a real photo into 2.5D), it should be able to have the same process, but in full 3D. That's all what I am asking for..

Comment: Increasing the resolution of the baked textures can help.